# Why is my media feature 'max-width' not working?

Tags: css, media-queries

This is a header image for my website:

```
header {
    background-image: url('../dogsimages/header-image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
```

However, I want to make the background image change for screens with less than 375px in width. So, I applied this media rule:

```
@media (max-width: 376px) {
    header {
        background-image: url('../dogsimages/german-shepher-for-header.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
    }
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work. It's very weird because if I change the media feature `(max-width: 375px)` with `(min-width: 375px)` it will work, but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: it looks good to me, does the image exist? do you see the changes applied in the developer console?

Comment: Good for debugging: comment out your `background-image`s and put different `background-color`s instead - that way, you will be able to find out what really happens.

Comment: Did you tried this...@media only screen and (max-width: 376px) {
  ......
}

Comment: have you got the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>`?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, I have attached image of nebula for large screen and image of spaceship for small screen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
html {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

header {
    background-image: url('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_brown.png');
/*     background-color:red; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}

@media (max-width: 376px) {
    header {
        background-image: url("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/space%20station.png");
/*        background-color:pink; */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

### Possible errors

- check image path
- check css file is embeded nicely

Also you can comment out the `background-color` to see the change.